# Swift error when loading website in webView

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

This is the `error` I get:

> Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>

I have a `segmentedController` inside my `webView` in there are three options:

```
    //MARK: segControlAction
@objc func segControlAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: // google
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        
    case 1: // amazon
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        
    case 2: // adidas
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.adidas.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    
    default:
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

*Google* and *Amazon* are working perfectly fine but `case 2` ("https://www.adidas.com") is not loading...What am I missing here??

Comment: Did you solve ?

Comment: @MartinJacob Nope. Changed it to „.de“ which is working

Comment: I have the same problem.